# Possible break point issue with Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

While debugging some C++ code using Visual Studio 2012 RC, I noticed a strange behavior with break points on class member functions and values of member variables.

When I set the break point on a class member function, VS 2012 puts the break point on the function curly bracket. Now, when hovering over a member variable used by the function, the value is always "uninitialized". However, pressing F10 to step to next line (first line in the function), the member variable is now changed to the correct value.

This looks like that values of member variables of a class is not loaded until stepping into the first line in the member function. But this is very confusing - what would be the point of breaking on the curly bracket then? (As is the default when setting break points on functions.)

*Breaking on class member function:*

[image: Breaking on bracket]

Member variable `active` is said to be `true` (which it really is not!)

*Stepping to next line with F10:*

[image]

Member variable `active` is now said to be `false` (which is correct.)

**Am I missing something here or is this an actual bug in Visual Studio 2012 RC?**

*Edit:* I found my copy of Visual Studio 2010 and tried this out. The behavior in regards to break points is the same. The difference lies in how IntelliSense handles the situation. In VS 2010, IntelliSense does not popup a tooltip at all when breaking on the curly brace, and in VS 2012 the tooltip is always displayed. I think the VS 2010 behavior is a lot better to avoid confusion.

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2010 exhibit the same debugger behavior?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I don't have Visual Studio 2010. Sorry.

Comment: I don't have it installed anymore, either.  I had always assumed this was either by design or was a quirk.  Basically, the `this` pointer isn't initialized yet when the debugger breaks on the `{`.

Comment: If this is by design, when would that ever be useful?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis FYI: I updated my question with the behavior of VS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the breakpoint on the curly brace, you are giving the debugger a choice between a rock and a hard place.  One hard place is the coding style convention, do you like K&R bracing?

```
void foo() {
   // etc..
}
```

How do you set a breakpoint on that one?  The debugger errs on the safe side, it sets a breakpoint on the function entry point.  When your breakpoint hits, you can use Debug + Windows + Assembly and you'll find out that it set the breakpoint on the very first machine code instruction in the function.  Almost always `push ebp`.  Which actually is a bit different from the normal way that the debugger tries to deal with ambiguous breakpoints, it usually looks ahead, not backwards.  So this was done very much intentionally.  Something that got addressed in the debugger for managed code, is is not just line-based but pays attention to the column as well.  That didn't flow back to the C++ debugger, it is still line-based.

So inspecting local variables isn't going to work out well, there aren't any.  Not until the function prologue gets executed that sets up the stack frame.  Including *this*.

The possible reason that the debugger looks backwards instead of forwards like it normally does is that you want to single-step through the constructors of class objects that are local variables.  Again, not something you can set a clear breakpoint on, other than rewinding the stack yourself and set a breakpoint on the constructor.  Who knows where.

Feature, not a bug.  The obvious workaround is to set a breakpoint on the first statement in the function body.  Everything is setup by then, stack frame as well as local variables.

Comment: I agree it's a feature and not a bug. I'd still argue that this is an issue with IntelliSense, though. It should at least visually indicate that it can't be sure about the value of variables.

Comment: IntelliSense has *nothing* to do with the debugger.  You'd have to claw through at least 4 or 5 levels of management to find a common boss at Microsoft.  The one reason the debugger works pretty well.

Comment: Interesting. For the record, I updated my question to highlight the different behavior of IntelliSense with VS 2010 and VS 2012. As my question dealt with break points and the debugger, I will accept this as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default on x86, C++ member functions use the thiscall calling convention<sup>(*)</sup>, which passes the `this` pointer via the `ecx` register.  The function may use this register for computations, though, so the debugger cannot rely on its value being the `this` pointer for the entire time the function is executing.

So, in an unoptimized build, as part of the function prologue that executes before the body of the function is entered, the `this` pointer will be "spilled" to the stack:  it is copied to a known offset on the stack so that the debugger can reliably get its value.  It is this copy of the `this` pointer that the debugger uses when you watch `this` or a member variable (which is implicitly accessed via the `this` pointer).

When you place a breakpoint on the opening brace of the `{`, the breakpoint is placed at the initial address of the function prologue, that is, at the first instruction that will execute when the function is called.  It is only after you step over this opening brace that the function prologue executes and the `this` pointer is spilled to the stack.

This can be useful if you need to debug through a function prologue.  It's a bit more obvious what is going on if you step through the disassembly (Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly).

---

(*)  On x64, there is only one calling convention, and it is a fastcall calling convention.  The `this` pointer will end up passed via the `rcx` register because it is the "first" argument to the function.

On x86, not all member functions use the thiscall calling convention, it's just the default.  Like other function types, you can specify the calling convention for the function.  This is done, for example, for COM components, which use the stdcall calling convention.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess this is more of an issue with IntelliSense then.